# Get top n combinations by multiple columns in R

Tags: r

Get top n combination based on multiple columns where the combination is defined as most occurrences. Let's say I need the top 3 occurrences from my input data:

Input Dataset:

```
Product <- c("XX","XX","XX","ZZ","YY","ZZ","YY","ZZ","YY","YY","XX",
                 "ZZ","XX","ZZ","ZZ","YY","YY","XX","YY","ZZ","ZZ","ZZ","ZZ","YY",
                 "XX","ZZ","ZZ","ZZ","YY","XX")
Grade <- c("A","B","A","C","B","A","C","B","C","A","B", "C","B","A","A","C","A","B","C","A",
               "C", "C","A","B","A","A","A","B","C","A")
Pass <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)

Sample_Dataset <- data.frame(Product, Grade, Pass) #input Dataset
```

Desired output:

```
> Top3_Combinations
      Product Grade Pass Occurences
1      ZZ     A    0          6
2      YY     C    1          5
3      XX     A    1          4
```

Also, include the combinations which have ties, like if there's another combination that has 4 occurrences include that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `count` to count combinations and `top_n` to select top 3 values. `top_n` would select all the tied values by default.

```
library(dplyr)
Sample_Dataset %>% count(Product, Grade, Pass, sort = TRUE) %>% top_n(3, n)


# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Product Grade  Pass     n
#  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 ZZ      A         0     6
#2 YY      C         1     5
#3 XX      A         1     4
```

---

In base R :

```
df1 <- aggregate(seq_along(Pass)~Product+Grade+Pass, Sample_Dataset, length)
names(df1)[4] <- 'n'
subset(df1, n %in% tail(sort(n), 3))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, what if I make a string variable (e.g  Var = "Product" "Grade" "Pass") so it's like Var[1] = "Product", Var[2] = "Grade",  Var[3] = "Pass". So I need to use loop on the Base R solution. I'll just use Var[i] instead (where i is 1 to 3).

Comment: If you have `Var` as `Var = c("Product", "Grade", "Pass")`, you can use non-standard evaluation to get counts. `Sample_Dataset %>% count(!!!syms(Var), sort = TRUE) %>% top_n(3, n)`

Comment: `syms` converts strings to symbols and `!!!` is used to evaluate them.

Answer (score 2):

The dplyr library has what you are looking for through the group_by() and summarize () functions. If you end up doing a lot of work in R this will be your bread and butter chain of functions for generating summary statistics.

```
Sample_Dataset %>% 
  group_by(Product,Grade,Pass) %>% #choose columns to aggregate 
  summarize(Occurances = n()) %>%  #count the number of occurrances with n() and write to summary column 
  arrange(desc(Occurances)) %>% #sort by occurances, descending  
  head(3) #limit to top 3 results
```

From there you can sort your data with arrange() and pick any arbitrary number for the top number of results to retain with head().

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Sample_Dataset)[, .N, .(Product, Grade, Pass)][N >= last(head(sort(unique(N), TRUE), 3L))]
```

And if there are ties and you want the top 3 rows:

```
setDT(Sample_Dataset)[, .N, .(Product, Grade, Pass)][order(-N), head(.SD, 3L)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
unique_df <- unique(data.frame(table(Sample_Dataset)))
top_3_ranked_desc <- head(with(unique_df, unique_df[rev(order(Freq)), ]), 3)
```

Base R bonus (in one obfuscated expression):

```
unique_df <- within(data.frame(head(sort(
  table(apply(Sample_Dataset, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")),
  decreasing = TRUE
), 3)),
{
  Var1 <- as.character(Var1)
  Product <- strsplit(Var1, ", ")[[1]]
  Grade <- strsplit(Var1, ", ")[[2]]
  Pass <- strsplit(Var1, ", ")[[3]]
  rm(Var1)
})
```

Comment: Hi on Base R Bonus, how can I make it a loop condition (from i to n)  like Var[i] so that we will not use all of the Var[1], Var[2],Var[3]. We will just use Var[i] instead.

Comment: @Bustergun if you want to retain Var1, remove the within statement and that will achieve the result.

Comment: @Bustergun I had misunderstood your second question. You can use an apply function and store a data.frame. Your result would then be a nested data.frame.